Tabs not showing on reaxt native 0.76.2
I am building a react-native 0.76.2 app using expo 52.0.10. I have used v0.76.2 of react-native. the code is really simple but I ran into an issue while following a tutorial online that the Tabs (Bottom Navigation) are not showing and this is my code snapshot below:
Folder structure:

Root _layout.tsx:

Tabs _layout.tsx:

package.json dependencies & dev dependencies:

I can't troubleshoot the issue here, is there any missing piece of code I have to write?
I have already tried a few questions over StackOverflow, but none of them helped.
